# Objective C NSArray addObject help/explanation

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

I'm new to Objective C so I was wondering if anyone could explain what is addObject is adding. I've been searching for a while and couldn't find anything.

```
define playerIdKey @"PlayerId"
define randomNumberKey @"randomNumber"
_orderOfPlayers = NSMutableArray

[_orderOfPlayers addObject:@{playerIdKey : [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].playerID, randomNumberKey : @(_ourRandomNumber)}];
```

More specifically, the whole @{var:var,var:var} is throwing me off since I originally though @ was only for string literals...

Thanks!

Comment: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to download a recent version of the Objective-C language manual.

@ is used to create NSString objects with either a literal, or a C string argument. It is just to create NSNumber objects. It is used to create NSArray and NSDictonary objects.

The first three lines are clearly not valid Objective-C. The last line adds an NSDictionary* to _orderOfPlayers.